# Spark UI SQL tab not displaying SQLs even when job is running

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a spark job to fetch data from oracle and load it to mongo DB. While running the job if i go to spark UI and open SQL tab, it does not show any data. However, Other tabs such as jobs, executers etc. are showing the job details. Can anyone suggest why is SQL tab not showing anything?

I an using spark 2.2.1 and opening UI in chrome and safari

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this. The tab is displayed only when spark optimise the sql.

Comment: Where did you get the answer from?

Comment: i got this answer by observing different jobs